# Window Resizes When Clicking Hamburger Button In Navbar

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I setup a mobile navbar that slides over from the left using React and JS but whenever I either click on a menu button in the navbar or if my ad carsouel moves the window resizes for some reason, also when i push the screen off to the right and bring it back its like it doesnt center itself, attached are pictures:

Before button press:
[image]

Right after first button press:
[image]

Menu button pressed:
[image]

After button is pressed to close window:
[image]

Piece of navbar js code that matters

```
<div>
        <nav className="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-custom ml-auto mr-auto justify-content-sm-start">
          <div className="container-fluid " id="navcontainer">
            <a id="logo" className="navbar-brand ">
              <img
                src="http://localhost:8080/img/logo.png"
                width="30"
                height="38"
                className=""
              />
            </a>
            <a href="#" id="titleBtn" className="navbar-brand titlebtn ">
              EqualityTees.com
            </a>
            <button
              className="navbar-toggler dropbtn navbar-light "
              type="button"
              id="hamburgerButton"
            >
              <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div
              className="collapse navbar-collapse d-flex flex-column mobilemenu"
              id="navbarCollapse"
            >
```

Javascript code for button clicks:

```
import $ from 'jquery'
import jquery from 'jquery'

$(document).ready(function () {
  //When hamburger button is clicked, open nav menu and pause carousel
  $('#carouselAd').carousel()
  $('.navbar-toggler, .overlay').on('click', function () {
    $('.mobilemenu, .overlay, .largebody').toggleClass('open')
    $('#carouselAd').carousel('pause')
  })

  //Shows the hamburger button when navbar is not open
  $('#hiddenToggler').on('click', function () {
    $('#hamburgerButton').show()
  })

  //Hides the hamburger button when navbar is open
  $('#hamburgerButton').on('click', function () {
    $('#hamburgerButton').hide()
  })
})
```

Css code:

```
@media (max-width: 992px) {
  .mobilemenu {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 75%;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: rgba(141, 137, 137, 0.9);
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    transition: all ease 0.25s;
    &.open {
      transform: translateX(0%);
    }
  }

.bodymove {
  transform: translateX(0%);
  transition: all ease 0.25s;
  &.open {
    transform: translateX(75%);
  }
}
```

and my whole body is being given the class name above(.bodymove)(the body is everything that is suppose to be pushed to the right). Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

1. Problem

I believe the problem is due to incapsulating the landing page components within the navbar, instead I would advise you to go with 'react-burger-menu' :easy to implement and smooth!

2.Solution

[source code](https://github.com/negomi/react-burger-menu)

[examples](https://negomi.github.io/react-burger-menu/)

Comment: I appreciate the response but i am trying to learn how to code it all myself without help from an additional library, thank you though.